# Prevent bumping an old question when editing

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, questions (or answers) contains a typo in the tag, title or description.

Is there a way to correct these mistakes without bumping the question? It could be a privilege, marking such edits as "Minor edit".

To prevent big changes from being done unnoticed, a maximum character limit of modifications could be introduced which is calculated since the last non-minor edit. Some characters (whitespace) could be ignored. Formatting like **bold** or *italic* could be ignored too in this character limit.

Comment: A general reminder: We _do not_ like small edits. If you're going to edit, make it count!

Comment: You can edit at most 5 of your own old posts in a day, as I discovered. To me editing to improve the quality of questions and answers for all future readers is important. I think if you try to make maximal improvements in each edit, it is ok since the limit of 5 is already imposed. I hope I have not caused any inconvenience in my recent mass edits.

Comment: @Jasper You have caused a great inconvenience. We don't like it when users try to improve the quality of their posts :)

Comment: I think this feature would be useful. Seems that it has been brought up before at one of the other sites some time ago. As usual, let's see what Jeff says. :)

Comment: @Stefano: the main reason for such a feature would be preventing new, relevant questions being pressed down by accepted questions which have small typos in it. I always try to edit as much as possible, but that's not always possible.

Answer (score 4):

This has been requested *many* times. As far as I can tell, there are a few reason why it still hasn't been implemented:

- Even high-rep users make mistakes

  Bumping a question makes them visible to others, so that they can be corrected quickly. Good peer review is more important than a 'clean' front page.
- Every question deserves a chance to get looked at

  Even if you deem a question to be of no value to visitors of the front page, it still might help someone, even if it's just the users who asked and answered it.

Rather than implementing something dangerous like this, I'd much rather have SO's new "Interesting" view as the default, rather than "Active".